# Session State as Page in the Application

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there any way we can have session state as a page in the application, instead of clicking the developer toolbar?

Comment: While it's a little old, have a look at this blog post: http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/01/using-sql-to-view-apex-session-state.html

Comment: Thanks. This works well for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. Can you please consider that the question is answered as per Dan's reply? 
This will help us to filter the un-answered ones easily.